# Font Awesome icons not showing

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I can't get the Font Awesome icons to show up. I've tried different CDNs and it does nothing on any browser.

CSS links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/color-defaults.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-white.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-blue.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-gray.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-black.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-white-black.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-white-green.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-white-red.min.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fonts.min.css" media="screen">        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/primary.css" media="screen">
```

Font Awesome HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <h1 class="h2">Follow</h1>
   <hr />
   <i class="fa facebook-official fa-lg"></i>
   <i class="fa google-plus-square fa-lg"></i>
   <i class="fa twitter-square fa-lg"></i>
   <i class="fa instagram fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: not enough html or css to go on - whats your site? you've posted local links you have to post your actual css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the wrong classes. Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h1 class="h2">Follow</h1>
    <hr />
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-lg"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-lg"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

You need to add `fa-` before each logo.

Comment: Thank you. I guess sometimes its the little things ya miss.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you always get form their documentations.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/archive/