# Font Awesome Icons not showing with css Content property

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to get Font Awesome icons to show up in my layout and so far only the circle play icon shows, I looked at [Font Awesome icons not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762881/font-awesome-icons-not-showing) but this is with the font awesome classes, I'm using the css `Content` property so I can change the icon with javascript, but some of the icons don't show, like seen here

```css
.button {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: black;
  border: solid black;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.controls.main .play-pause::before {
  content: "\f144";
}

.controls.main .prev::before {
  content: "\f04a";
}

.controls.main .next::before {
  content: "\f04e";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="controls main">
      <span class="button prev"></span>
      <span class="button play-pause"></span>
      <span class="button next"></span>
 </div>
```

is there a reason for this, like did i do anything wrong? if you want to see the whole project: [go here](https://jsfiddle.net/FoxyGames/bn7u9hys/66/)

(btw does anyone know any cool animated play-pause buttons? i'm just curious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FontAwesome displays different icons depending on the `font-weight` property, and the `\f04a` and `\f04e` icons are not available on the default `font-weight` of `400` in the free version. However, you can still use the icons using a `font-weight` of `600`. Example:

```css
.button {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: black;
  border: solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.controls.main .play-pause::before {
  content: "\f144";
}

.controls.main .prev::before {
  content: "\f04a";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.controls.main .next::before {
  content: "\f04e";
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="controls main">
      <span class="button prev"></span>
      <span class="button play-pause"></span>
      <span class="button next"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: omg this worked, thank you so much